# How to make Bottle print stacktrace when running through apache modwsgi?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, bottle

When running Bottle as a standalone server it's very easy to do:

```
from bottle import run, Bottle

run(app=app, host=config.get('bottle_host', 'localhost'), port=config.get('bottle_port', '8080'),
                            debug=config.get('debug', True), server=config.get('server_middleware', 'tornado'))
```

The problem is that with wsgi I have to do this:

```
app = Bottle()
```

And `Bottle` constructor doesn't have any debug parameter. So what can I do to get the stacktrace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import bottle
bottle.debug(True)
```

If you look at the source you can see that this function is called by the `run` function when providing `debug`.

Comment: Mentioned in the docs [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#debug-mode)