# How to make Bottle print error message in 500 response?

Tags: uwsgi, bottle

I'm trying to debug why Bottle can no longer find a template, but it doesn't tell me which template is actually missing:

```
  File "/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 3222, in __init__
    raise TemplateError('Template %s not found.' % repr(name))
bottle.TemplateError
```

Neither the console nor the web page contain the formatted version of `Template %s not found.` anywhere.

I have enabled debugging (when debugging is disabled the stack trace does not show up on the web page).

The route handler is literally just `@bottle.post('/request')`.

This is distinct from [How to make Bottle print stacktrace when running through apache modwsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25572176/96588), since the answer there is to enable debugging.

Using the latest stable Bottle, 0.12.13.

Comment: Which version of Bottle? My test program (Bottle 0.12.13) *does* print the missing template name.

Comment: Hmm. Posted my code as an answer in the hopes that it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - is your code substantially different? Hoping you'll spot a difference.

```
from bottle import Bottle, template

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return template('foo')  # template "foo" does not exist

app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)  # Note: no debug required
```

Response:

```
% curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Error: 500 Internal Server Error</title>
            <style type="text/css">
              html {background-color: #eee; font-family: sans;}
              body {background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #ddd;
                    padding: 15px; margin: 15px;}
              pre {background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 5px;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Error: 500 Internal Server Error</h1>
            <p>Sorry, the requested URL <tt>&#039;http://127.0.0.1:8080/&#039;</tt>
               caused an error:</p>
            <pre>Template &#039;foo&#039; not found.</pre>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Note that the error message contains the missing template name:

> Template 'foo' not found.

Comment: No, the error message is just as I posted it. The HTML just contains the same string. The code is substantially different; it's a large legacy application.

Comment: Ah, too bad. Not sure we can help without seeing some of that code. I'm happy to have another look if you're able to post a pared down version of your application. Perhaps just the code for the route handler in question?